# Using a combobox dropdown list with PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to display a picture in a picturebox using a combobox dropdownlist, populated with genres of books; Networking, Programming, Web.  When the user selects a particular book, a picture of the book cover will be displayed.  I've tried a bunch of different ways but nothing seems to work. I have thisGenreComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged so I guess it's a matter of the if/else if statement. Below is what I've been trying, I'm sure it's way way off.  Suggestions? Many thanks!

```
        //if ((string)thisGenreComboBox.SelectedItem == ("Networking"))
        //if (thisGenreComboBox.Text == "Networking")
        if (thisGenreComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            thisGenrePictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(@"networkingcover.jpg");
        }
```

*** Edited ***

Below is what I eventually came up with and works perfect for my needs.  Also, I applied the same to a ListBox and that works fine as well.

```
        switch (thisGenreComboBox.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    thisGenrePictureBox.ImageLocation = ("NetworkCover.jpg");
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    thisGenrePictureBox.ImageLocation = ("ProgramCover.jpg");
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                {
                    thisGenrePictureBox.ImageLocation = ("WebProgramCover.jpg");
                    break;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do such task.

**Option 1**

For example you can use a **naming convention** for your images, for example, if you have Networking, Programming and Web books name your images with NetworkingCover.jpg, ProgrammingCover.jpg and WebCover.jpg.

Fill your combobox:

```
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add("Networking");
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add("Programming");
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add("Web");
```

Then you can use this code in `SelectedIndexChanged` event of comboBox:

```
if(thisGenreComboBox.SelectedIndex>-1)
{
    var imageName = string.Format("{0}Cover.jpg", thisGenreComboBox.SelectedItem);
    // I suppose your images are located in an `Image` folder
    // in your application folder and you have this items to your combobox.
    var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "images" , imageName);
    thisGenrePictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
}
```

**Option 2**

As another option you can create a class for your book:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public overrides ToString()
    {
        return this.Title;
    }
}
```

And then create your books and fill your combobox:

```
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add(
    new Book(){Title= "Networking" , Image = "NetworkingCover.jpg"});
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add(
    new Book(){Title= "Programming" , Image = "ProgrammingCover.jpg"});
thisGenreComboBox.Items.Add(
    new Book(){Title= "Web" , Image = "WebCover.jpg"});
```

And then in `SelectedIndexChnaged` event of combobox:

```
if(thisGenreComboBox.SelectedIndex>-1)
{
    var imageName = ((Book)thisGenreComboBox.SelectedItem).Image;

    // I suppose your images are located in an `Image` folder
    // in your application folder and you have this items to your combobox.
    var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "images" , imageName);
    thisGenrePictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(file);
}
```

Comment: Reza, thank you for your time and effort in assisting me with my issue.

Comment: @Heavy It would be great if you mark the answer as accepted by click on check mark near the answer :)